# how to get rid from the unreachable problem in phycharm software

Tags: python, while-loop

The increment section of the while loop is showing unreachable in phycharm. what should I do to fix it?

```
while i<8:
    if board[i]==board[i+1] and board[i+1]==board[i+2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    i=i+3
    
while j<4:

    if board[j]==board[j+3] and board[j+3]==board[j+6]:
        return True 
    else:
        return False
    j=j+1
```

As you can see the increment section is showing unreachable. What should I do to fix it?

[image: showing unreachable,cannot run]

Comment: Well, remove the unreachable code or make it reachable again. Currently, the function will return at first iteration  before reaching the line `i += 3`

Comment: You added return in if and else conditions which will return back to previous call and the next line wont be exeucted

Comment: The return statement will always be called because it is in both if and else

Answer (score 0):

Both your `if` and `else` statements have a `return` statement, which prompts an exit from the function.

As such, the interpreter will never end up at the increment operations, because it will always exit the function before it reaches these lines. PyCharm isn't wrong about this, the increments just aren't accessible in any way.